# Как совершить вывод только один раз

Tags: python

```
c = 0
d = []
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if a < -3000 or a > 0 or b < -3000 or b > 0:
    print("Error")
else:
    for d in range(min(a, b) + 1, max(a, b) - 1):
        if d % 2 != 0:
            c += 1
            print("Нечетных чисел " + str(c))
```

написал код, а при выводе выходит что-то по типу:
Нечетных чисел 1
Нечетных чисел 2
Нечетных чисел 3
Нечетных чисел 4
Нечетных чисел 5
Нечетных чисел 6
Нечетных чисел 7
Нечетных чисел 8
Нечетных чисел 9
Нечетных чисел 10
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы мне выводился лишь конечный результат? В этом случае только 10

Comment: Зачем Вы сделали столько отступов перед `print`?

Comment: убрать в последней строке 8 пробелов

Comment: в том то и дело, что в оно должно выполняться в случае else

Comment: Так в `else` и вынесите его. Сейчас он у вас в `else` `for` и `if`.

Comment: Ясно, извините за мою невнимательность. Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: Количество нечетных числе в диапазоне можно посчитать и по формуле, не используя цикл.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй вынести print

```
c = 0
d = []
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if a < -3000 or a > 0 or b < -3000 or b > 0:
    print("Error")
else:
    for d in range(min(a, b) + 1, max(a, b) - 1):
        if d % 2 != 0:
            c += 1
print("Нечетных чисел " + str(c))
```

Comment: Один таб всё же нужен тому принту, он в else должен попасть

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать ещё следующим образом:

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
def chet (a,b):
    d = []
    c = 0
    if a < -3000 or a > 0 or b < -3000 or b > 0:
        print("Error")
    else:
        for d in range(min(a, b) + 1, max(a, b) - 1):
            if d % 2 != 0:
                c += 1
        return str(c)

print(chet(a,b))
```